# How to use date of different formats in where condtion to get ouptut in SAS

Tags: sql, datetime, sas, proc-sql

I have a query which uses *date2*

```
call symput('date2',strip(" ' "||put(intx('month',today(),-2,'B'),date9.))||" ' "));
%put &date2;
```

which basically gives the first day of 2 months prior to running date

and I Have another date which is *'30jan2015'd*

I want to write a where condition for date column such as

```
where datecolumn >= '30jan2015'd and datecolumn <= &date2;
```

When I tried this I am getting an error saying `Expression using greater than or equal has components that are of different data types.`

Could anyone help me on how I should change the query to make the where condition run, please?

Comment: The code `30jan2015'd` in your question is missing a leading `'`.  The date literal should be `'30jan2015'd`

Comment: Try to replace `&date2` with `"&date2"d`.

Answer (score 4):

A SAS Date value is either a **number**, representing number of days from `01-JAN-1960`, or a **date literal**, which is a construct of form `"<day>-<month>-<year>"D`.

Macro variables are resolved using the `&` symbol in source code, not `$`.  Are you coming to SAS from a different coding language such as `PHP` ?

Because your ranges check is endpoint inclusive you can simplify the `where` statement you are coding by using a `BETWEEN` operator instead.

Example:

```
* place an unformatted date value (i.e. data value number) in macro variable;
data _null_;
  call symput('date2',intx('month',today(),-2,'B')); 
run;

* more code using a date literal and resolved macro variable;
data myDateRangeSubset;
  set BigData;
  where datecolumn between '30jan2015'd and &date2;
run;
```

If you are still getting log messages about *different data types* you will likely have to convert the `datecolumn` from string to the appropriate SAS date value.

```
  where input(datecolumn,date9.) between '30jan2015'd and &date2;
```